# How to call an ASP.NET MVC 3 action using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

How do I call ASP.NET MVC 3 action using jQuery?

Actually, in my `index.cshtml` I have a combo-box which have sectorz names from the database. Whenever I click an option,

```
  onclick="Get_sector("some_sector_Name")"
```

the above jQuery function is called. Below is the jQuery function.

```
function Get_sector(sec)
{
    //$.post("/Main/selected_sector?sectrz=" + sec , insertCallback);

    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Main/selected_sector",
        data: "sectrz=" + sec,

        success: function (result) {
            alert("submitted");
        },

        error: function (req, status, error) {
            alert("Sorry!!");
        }
    });
}
```

Whenever I click the combo-box option I want to load a new action named `Selected_sector`. In this action complete information of the `selected_sectorz` will show. For example, the selected area has 100 houses for sale, etc. (Actually I'm developing a property portal site for my dad's business. I'm a student and new in ASP.NET MVC 3.)

```
public ActionResult Selected_sector(string sectrz)
{
    var sec = DB.sectors.Include("Homes_Sale").OrderBy(m=>m.sectorId).Where(m=>m.sectorName==sectrz).ToList();
    return View(sec);
}
```

When I then insert a breakpoint at this line:

```
return View(); // return action of Selected_sector
```

then the Selected_sector action is not loading. `index.cshtml` is loading again.

I have searched a lot on the Internet, but I found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try returning a partial view instead of a view. That is,

```
return PartialView("ViewName");
```

Comment: yes sir i have checked '
        async:true,
        dataType: "html" ' but same problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be in your view. If you have created a view **"Selected_sector"**, then set a breakpoint in the view and see if the model is having any content in there.

More details:

You should have a view named **"Selected_sector"** or special which view to load, `return view("viewname", model);`.

Comment: no sir at this time no model is passing in this view simply return view(); is use help m m stuck]

Comment: `      public ActionResult Sale()
        {

            var sec =    DB.sectors.Include("Homes_Sale").OrderBy(m=>m.sectorId).ToList();
            return View(sec);

        }`

Comment: above is my sale Action method and---[HttpPost]  <hr/>
        public ActionResult Select_sector(string sectrz)
        {
            //return RedirectToAction("Whyus", "Main");
            return View();
        }'

Answer (score 0):

Some questions about your problem:

1. Why are you using underscores on action names? [.NET Naming convetions](http://www.akadia.com/services/naming_conventions.html)
2. What are you trying to do with the result of your action? Iterate over it and create some html? Display the results on the screen? (My answer depends on this answer).

Some advice:

If you use `return View(sec);` in your action, you should have a View with the same name of your action (`Selected_sector` in this case) or use `return View("ViewName",yourModel);` instead to show your result. If you submit an HTTP POST to your action, put the annotation `[HttpPost]` in the top like Shark said.

If you are a beginner at ASP.NET MVC 3, I recommend the book *[Professional ASP.NET MVC 3](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/productCd-1118076583.html)*.